# A doubt on the proof of a Characterization of Isometries - Axler's linear algebra book

Tags: linear-algebra

In Axler's linear algebra book, 3rd edition, in page 229, the author states the following theorem:

> **7.42 Characterization of isometries**
>   Suppose $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$.
>   Then the following are equivalent:
>   (a) $S$ is an isometry;
>   (b) $\langle S u, S v \rangle = \langle u, v \rangle$ for all $u, v \in V$;
>   (c) $S e_1, \dotsc, S e_n$ is orthonormal for every orthonormal list of vectors $e_1, \dotsc, e_n$ in $V$;
>   (d) there exists an orthonormal basis $e_1, \dotsc, e_n$ of $V$ such that $S e_1, \dotsc, S e_n$ is orthonormal;

In proving that (c) $\implies$ (d), Axler just states that it's obvious. However, I don't find it... In (c) there could be no orthonormal basis, but still exist orthonormal lists. In (d) we affirm the existence of one. This could be easy if we were assuming that $V$ was finite dimensional(Gram-Schmidt Procedure), however the theorem is silent in that regard.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Excellent observation. In fact, (d) explictly claims that $\dim V=n$

Comment: From the beginning of chapter $\;7\;$ Axler remarks that $\;V\;$ is *a finite dimensional linear space*

Comment: For whatever it’s worth (and I’m not convinced it’s much), you could accommodate the infinite-dimensional case by changing (d) to say “for every finite-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$ there exists an orthonormal basis $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ of $W$ such that $Se_1,\dotsc,Se_n$ is orthonormal.”

Comment: @DonAntonio Many thanks ;)